# Wordpress plugin installation: Missing zlib

Tags: php, wordpress

I am installing a wordpress plugin but I am getting an error:

```
Downloading install package from http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/theme-my-login.6.3.8.zip…
Unpacking the package…
Abort class-pclzip.php : Missing zlib extensions
```

I have checked with the command `php -m` for installed modules and I am getting "zlib" as installed module.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: check phpinfo() at the root of the wordpress installation

Comment: what should I check in phpinfo()?

Comment: check for "zlib" if its enabled in there and no other local settings are disabling the extension

Comment: I don't know why i got -ve rating for my question. Instead of putting a -ve rating it will be good if that fellow respond the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem hence i am answering my own question.

I have downloaded the latest version of php and compiled with "--with-zlib" option. It fixed the error. I don't know why because if my previous setup is not supporting zlip than it must through "php -r 'var_dump(function_exists("gzopen"));" false but it returned true.